# Java how to print in upper case

Tags: java

```
s.append("\n"); // new line
key = num[15]; // d 
s.append(line3.substring(key, key + 1));
key = num[17]; // r
s.append(line1.substring(key, key + 1));
key = num[4]; // o
s.append(line1.substring(key, key + 1));
key = num[2]; // n
s.append(line8.substring(key, key + 1));
key = num[1]; // e
s.append(line2.substring(key, key + 1));
s.append(" ");
key = num[0]; // B
s.append(line10.substring(key, key + 1));
key = num[1]; // E
s.append(line1.substring(key, key + 1));
key = num[0]; //T
```

I want to display the word B and E as uppercase characters. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `Character` class' `toUpper` method.

```
Character.toUpper( 'b' ); //B
```

You can read more about the `Character` class and its other methods at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

now this is only when working with the `char`'s vs `String`'s, so if you are doing `String`'s I would go with Nicole's answer and use the corresponding `String` method as such:

```
s.append( line10.substring( key, key+1 ).toUpperCase() ); //B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
String str = "hello"; 
String strUpperCase = str.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of question has been answered already [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147319/how-to-convert-input-char-to-uppercase-automatically-in-java). Or you can follow [This link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_touppercase.htm). Please do some research before asking the questions.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a very complete response to your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538000/uppercase-or-lowercase-a-specific-character-in-a-word-java)

And I suggest to use [`.charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) function in place of `.substring` function for optimize your code.